# What's wrong with this KNP string matching algorithm?

Tags: c, string-matching

I have written the KNP based on the pseudo code in wikipedia for [KNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Description_of_and_pseudocode_for_the_search_algorithm)

But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to give the proper result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getNext(char *p, int next[])
{
  int i, j;
  int m = strlen(p);
  next[0] = -1;

  for(j=1; j<m; j++)
  {
    i = next[j - 1]; 
    while((i >= 0) && (p[j - 1] != p[i]))
    {
        i = next[i];
    }
    next[j] = i+1;
  }
}

int knp(char *text, char* pattern, int T[])
{
  int m = 0; // The beginning of the current match in text
  int i = 0; // The position of the current character in W

  int pattern_length = strlen(pattern) - 1;

  while( m+i < pattern_length)
  {
     if( pattern[i] == text[m+i]) // Made a mistake here and wrote: text[m]
      {
         if(i == )
         {
                 return m;
             }
             else
                 i = i + 1;
       }
       else
       {
           if( T[i] > -1 )
              i = T[i];
           else
              i = 0;

             m = m + i - T[i];
       }
  }
  return -1; // If we reach here, the string is not found
}
int main()
{
  int next[7];
  int i;
  char *ptr = "ababaca";
  char *text = "ababbababaaaababacaacd";

  getNext(ptr, next);
  for(i=0; i<7; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\t",next[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  printf("Pattern match at: %d",knp(text, ptr, next));
}
```

Note: Only the KNP is taken from wiki. The table building idea i have taken from another book ;-) , verifying that it indeed gives correct result matching that in the wiki.

**The above code is now corrected (as per the answer from Michael) for everyone's benefit. I have put my error (in commented out form) due to which the question was put up here.**

Comment: Use a debugger and do your work.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: If it was as easy to debug all problems, sites like stackoverflow won't have been into existence. Moreover, i am not telling anyone to debug MY code. This one is openly available in wiki, and it is expected lot of people might have used that before me. If anyone has already done it i am asking for that. And the worst thing is, my interview date is too close.

Comment: what result are you expecting vs what are you seeing?  This is likely to be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: I am seeing -1 in all cases. Including the text string and the pattern mentioned in main. np if it is closed, but i wonder how come the wiki code gives answers like this.

Comment: Correcting the code above, based on answer from @Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a typo in your transcription:

```
if( pattern[i] == text[i])
```

should be:

```
if( pattern[i] == text[m + i])
```

---

I'd also suggest that you remove the call to `strlen(pattern)` from within your loop and call it once before the loop starts.